# Bootstrap textarea issue in Google Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, when I am using Bootstrap, textareas do not properly work.

If it is written for exemple: **"fi"**, the cursor never go between the "f" and the "i". It pass directly from **"fi|"** to **"|fi"**.

I have made some sample, for see the behavior:

1. With Bootstrap: http://www.square-it.wtf/test-with-bootstrap
2. Without Bootstrap: http://www.square-it.wtf/test

The sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Textarea behavior <mark>with</mark> bootstrap</h3>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40">fi</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Chrome version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)

It seems in insignificant, but I need a perfect textarea behavior for other functionality in my website.

Is there a way to fixe it, **without updating Chrome** version?  (I can not force users to have the latest Chrome version)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You missed `form-control` class. Have a look at this:

```
<textarea name="" id="input" class="form-control" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
```